# Why do basic_string::size() & '_M_string_length' in same class, return **different** values, even though size() returns 'size_type _M_string_length'?

Tags: stdstring

I wanted to see the actual definition of this function size() and lenght() of basic_string, because in his book, Bjarne had written that 'strlen() is a log(N) opera-
tion, whereas string::size() is a simple read'. And then I found that, there is '_M_string_length' (declared private at line 156 in bits/basic_string.h)

I made the _M_string_length member public in the class (and commented the private one).

But,

```
std::string str="Hello"
std::cout<<str._M_string_length<<'\n'<<str.length()<<'\n'<<str.size()<<'\n';
```

gave this output:

```
140723012417600       //kept changing in various runs
5
5
```

Why is _M_string_length and size() are different... even though size() also returns _M_string_length as it is, and it's type is also size_type? Is it due to that _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT?

For the _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT, i ran the following...

```
cat /usr/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/* | grep "#define _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT"
```

and in all directories inside them... like /usr/include/ and /c++/7/ and its subdirectories but i couldn't find if it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't safely edit/change *anything* in the `std` namespace and expect to have it work in a sensible way.  You get undefined behavior.

What probably happened is that your change changed the layout of the basic_string class, but you're still linking with the same libstdc++ shared library object that is assuming the old layout, so things break randomly.

Comment: So, is there something like a 'copy' of the original library in the C++ standard library, to which it is assuming similarity with? And, what about that thing that it breaks 'randomly' ; Can you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @AdiG15: The C++ standard library shared object is a binary, compiled from the shared library sources as a separate translation unit.  If you change those sources without rebuilding the shared object, you violate the rule that declarations must be identical between translation units and get undefined behavior.